# How to Create an Endnote able to Link to the Current Section with "Autolabelling"?

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I would like tu use footnotes and chapter endnotes in my document (chapter endnotes will be used only for "large" notes).

In endnotes, I would be glad to be able to ref/link to the current chapter(/section/subsection/...) where the endnote was called and the text just before it because I found inconvenient to just have the list of endnotes at the end of a chapter and don't remember what extactly the note is dealing with (the context). So I would like to be able to cite a part of the text and the section number into the endnote in order to put the endnote in context and then help the reader...

Is there a way to have something like a "`\myendnote`" command with two arguments and ables to:

1. Print the first argument in the body where the command is called AND in the endnote (between quotes "" and in italic in the exemple below);
2. Print, in the endnote text, the link to the current chapter, section, subsection, etc. where the command is called and even the footnote number (if the endnote is called into a footnote, see MWE). This last functionality (dealing with the footnote could be adressed with another command like a "`\myfootendnote`" or with another argument, I'm open to everything...);

```
\newcommand{\myendnote}[2]{%
% Here maybe something to auto generate the "autolabel" ???
{#1}\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{autolabel} \nameref{autolabel}, p. \pageref{autolabel}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
```

**See the final working solution below (EDIT 3)**

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{counter-format=alph}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% Only used for verbatim footnotes
\VerbatimFootnotes

\newcommand{\myendnote}[2]{%
% Here maybe something to auto generate the "autolabel" ???
{#1}\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{autolabel} \nameref{autolabel}, p. \pageref{autolabel}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!


Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no 2}!%
}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

And here the expected results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### EDIT 3: final working solution thanks to [John Kormylo answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633156/262081)

The final solution works with several chapters with endnotes but the hyperlinks related to footnote - in the endnote list - doesn't redirect to the right page but print the correct number.

The `\myendnote` command call is simplified because the user doesn't need to pass the counters as arguments anymore, the command deals alone with labelling automaticaly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{counter-format=alph}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% Only used for verbatim footnotes
\VerbatimFootnotes

\newcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}
\newcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}{0}
\newcounter{endnoteLabelInFootnote}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelInFootnote}{0}
\newcounter{endnoteLabelInFootnoteUsed}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelInFootnoteUsed}{0}

\newcommand{\autoLabelling}{%
\stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}%
\label{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}%
}%

\newcommand{\autoLabellingFootnote}{%
\stepcounter{endnoteLabelInFootnote}%
\label{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelInFootnote\thechapter}%
}%

% Modification of the command in order to deal with call inside a footnote
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myendnote}{m m o}{%
  % <code>
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{% code when no optional argument #3 is passed
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\stepcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}\emph{\S{}~\ref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelUsed} \nameref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelUsed}, p. \pageref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelUsed}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
    {% code when the optional argument #3 is present
% Note that, on the next line, the \stepcounter is moved after the \ref and \nameref in order to link to the current section and after to the footnote numer
    {#1}\autoLabelling\autoLabellingFootnote\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelUsed} \nameref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelUsed}, \stepcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}\stepcounter{endnoteLabelInFootnoteUsed}footnote \ref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelInFootnoteUsed\thechapter}, p. \pageref{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelInFootnoteUsed\thechapter}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
% #3 : Optionnal argument if command passed inside a footnote

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{A First section}
\subsection{A First subsection}

\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}:! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]:! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\printendnotes
\setcounter{endnote}{0} %<<<<<< added

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A second section}
\subsection{A second subsection}

\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}:! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]:! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\printendnotes
\setcounter{endnote}{0} %<<<<<< added

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\section{A third section}
\subsection{A third subsection}
   
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}:! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]:! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\printendnotes
\setcounter{endnote}{0} %<<<<<< added
\end{document}
```

### EDIT 1: First Attempt

My **Non** Working Solution is to use 2 new commands:

- `\autoLabelling` command which create a label based on a counter `endnoteLabelCnt`:

```
\newcommand{\autoLabelling}{
\stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\label{\arabic{endnoteLabelCnt}}
}
```

- `\myendnote` as presented above but with 3 arguments, the last one is the label created thanks to the counter `endnoteLabelCnt` with `\autoLabelling` command.

Here a Minimal **NON** Working Exemple:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{counter-format=alph}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% Only used for verbatim footnotes
\VerbatimFootnotes

\newcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}

\newcommand{\autoLabelling}{
\stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\label{\arabic{endnoteLabelCnt}}
}

\newcommand{\myendnote}[3]{%
% Here maybe something to auto generate the "autolabel" ???
{#1}\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
% #3 : Label

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
    \autoLabelling
    
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!
 
\verb!{\arabic{AbsoluteSectionNumber}} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}{\arabic{endnoteLabelCnt}}

% Warning: \autoLabelling command is called into the footnote here:
Some text with a foot note\footnote{\autoLabelling\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no 2} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 2}{\arabic{endnoteLabelCnt}}}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

The results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem is highlighted with a red rectangle: all the links are pointing to the footnote number "1" (which corresponds to the last use of `\autoLabelling` command in the footnote). The first endnote "a" should point to the subsection 2.1.1 as schown in the expected results above.
It seems that the counter `endnoteLabelCnt` is "incremented everywhere" even before the last call of `\autoLabelling` command...

---

### EDIT 2: Second Attempt after follow up comment

The solution proposed by John Kormylo works inside a chapter but I can't make it works if there are several chapters in my document.

I tried to modify the `\myendnote` command in order to deal with call inside a footnote thanks to an optional argument:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myendnote}{m m m o}{%
  % <code>
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}{% code when no optional argument #4 is passed
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
    {% code when the optional argument #4 is present
% Note that, on the next line, the \stepcounter is moved after the \ref and \nameref in order to link to the current section and after to the footnote numer
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, \stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}footnote \ref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
% #3 : Label
% #4 : Optionnal argument if command passed inside a footnote
```

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setenotez{counter-format=alph}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% Only used for verbatim footnotes
\VerbatimFootnotes

\newcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}

\newcommand{\autoLabelling}{%
  \stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
  % Modification here by adding "\thechapter"
  %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \label{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}
}

% Modification of the command in order to deal with call inside a footnote
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myendnote}{m m m o}{%
  % <code>
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}{% code when no optional argument #4 is passed
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
    {% code when the optional argument #4 is present
% Note that, on the next line, the \stepcounter is moved after the \ref and \nameref in order to link to the current section and after to the footnote numer
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, \stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}footnote \ref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
% #3 : Label
% #4 : Optionnal argument if command passed inside a footnote
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{A First section}
\subsection{A First subsection}
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!
 
\verb!{\arabic{AbsoluteSectionNumber}} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}
\printendnotes

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A second section}
\subsection{A second subsection}
   
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!
 
\verb!{\arabic{AbsoluteSectionNumber}} :!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt} :!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

**But it doesn't work in the second chaper endnote list, I get only ?? characters...**

Comment: The first problem is that the endnotes are sent unexpanded, The second is that a `\label` inside a footnote does not work (no `\newlabel` in aux file).

Comment: BTW, I noticed that endnotes writes to an .ent file, while enotez writes the notes to the aux file.  I'm surprised no one writes the notes to a savebox.  It would be relatively easy to implement.  I wouldn't recommend it for more than one page worth of notes, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of works.  It prints the footnote counter, but `\nameref` still prints "A Section".

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\setenotez{counter-format=alph}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% Only used for verbatim footnotes
\VerbatimFootnotes

\newcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}

\newcommand{\autoLabelling}{%
  \stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
  \label{test\theendnoteLabelCnt}
}

\newcommand{\myendnote}[3]{% #1=
% Here maybe something to auto generate the "autolabel" ???
{#1}\endnote{\stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
% #3 : Label

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
    \autoLabelling
    
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!
 
\verb!{\arabic{AbsoluteSectionNumber}} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{test\theendnoteLabelCnt}

% Warning: \autoLabelling command is called into the footnote here:
Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{test\theendnoteLabelCnt}}\autoLabelling

\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

---

If you intend to call `\printendnotes` more than once, you will need two counters.  All labels must have unique names, so you can't reuse the old numbers.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setenotez{counter-format=alph}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% Only used for verbatim footnotes
\VerbatimFootnotes

\newcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}{0}
\newcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}
\setcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}{0}

\newcommand{\autoLabelling}{%
  \stepcounter{endnoteLabelCnt}
  % Modification here by adding "\thechapter"
  %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \label{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}
}

% Modification of the command in order to deal with call inside a footnote
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myendnote}{m m m o}{%
  % <code>
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}{% code when no optional argument #4 is passed
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\stepcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
    {% code when the optional argument #4 is present
% Note that, on the next line, the \stepcounter is moved after the \ref and \nameref in order to link to the current section and after to the footnote numer
    {#1}\autoLabelling\endnote{\emph{\S{}~\ref{#3} \nameref{#3}, \stepcounter{endnoteLabelUsed}footnote \ref{#3}, p. \pageref{#3}, " {#1} "~}: {#2}}}
}
% #1 : Text displayed in body document (which have the endnote superscript mark) AND in the endnote between quotes "" and in italic.
% #2 : Text of the endnote
% #3 : Label
% #4 : Optionnal argument if command passed inside a footnote
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{A First section}
\subsection{A First subsection}
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!
 
\verb!{\arabic{AbsoluteSectionNumber}} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt} :! \myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\printendnotes

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A second section}
\subsection{A second subsection}
   
\verb!\myendnote{Some text with an end note}{text in the end note no 1}!
 
\verb!{\arabic{AbsoluteSectionNumber}} :!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}

Some text with a foot note\footnote{\verb!\myendnote{footnote text}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt} :!\myendnote{Some text with an end note \theendnoteLabelCnt}{text in the end note no \theendnoteLabelCnt}{\thechapter\theendnoteLabelCnt}[footnote]}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly inside of a chapter ! Thanks a lot ! However, do you no by chance if there is a way to make it works in another chapter also without any further action for the user? I tried to replace `test\theendnoteLabelCnt}` by `\arabic{chapter}\theendnoteLabelCnt}` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Remember that the labels are not expanded until `\printendnotes`.  You may need to reset the chapter counter and add `\addtoendnotes{\stepcounter{chapter}}` at the beginning of each chapter.  Also, chapter 1 endnote 1 will produce label 11 (eleven).

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. I tried something but it doesn't work (see my second edit). I think I don't understand how counter works in LaTeX... Sorry.